# Python turn on mic(without modules)

Tags: python

I've found out that the only way to turn on mic is using pip and installing modules, I want to code it on my own and im not allowed for downloading modules anyway. I even tried a batch script which writes data in a file but it was of no use, is there anyway i can accomplish turning on mic in windows 10 without downloading modules??

Comment: What do you mean exactly by turning on? Mute and Unmute the microphone?

Comment: I'm not sure, but sounds unrealistic. You'd probably need some module to talk to Windows API, but it's far more complex than just downloading some easy to set up Python module. Alternatively you'd need to switch to C++, implement usage of mic using Windows API (assuming the C++ Windows SDK is already provided by OS) and load such program in Python

Comment: i don't think i can install module but changing to c++ is not possible either for me after all im comfy in python, i don't even know c++ in fact

Comment: @Dev since most of low-level and cross platform code either uses existing Python modules or plain C++, I guess you have no choice but to use Python modules. Python is made in such a way that it's a very simple language, and tons of functionality are built added modules making Python programs more complex and convenient.

Comment: k, i found out that i can do this with PyAudio tho when i install it then i get an error saying it needs microsoft visual studio, how do i accomplish installing pyaudio using pip in command line??????

Comment: Google first, then create another question if still in trouble (but you really should Google better, all the answers are always here)

Comment: ive tried it did not work